# How can I change the texture in a Scene2D Image using libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

How can I change the texture in a Scene2D Image?

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html

There is no such method in the docs. I create mine by providing its constructor a texture reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to change the drawable and wrap your new texture in a `SpriteDrawable`

```
Texture texture = ...;
Image image = new Image(texture);

// switch to a new texture
Texture newTexture = ...;
image.setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(newTexture)));
```

Comment: Based on that, would `((SpriteDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getSprite().setTexture(newTexture);` work as well?

Comment: If you create the Image via the Texture constructor, then it won't work, because it will be a TextureRegionDrawable instead of a SpriteDrawable.

Comment: So I should instead use the method you posted? I was just trying to avoid creating new objects, but I suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hmm don't mean to be a downer, but why didn't they just create a `.setTexture` function for the `Image` class.

Comment: Then they'd also need to add a `setTextureRegion`, and a `setSprite` and maybe a `setPixmap` and ... you get what I mean.